# Cabal update: Failed to download

Tags: haskell, cabal

Despite repeated attempts, Cabal does not update.
Why is Cabal not working properly?
What should I do?
The last update dates back to 89 days.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.0.0.1
compiled using version 2.0.1.1 of the Cabal library
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
dieVerbatim: user error (cabal.exe: Failed to download
http://objects-us-west-1.dream.io/hackage-mirror/01-index.tar.gz : No Status
Code could be parsed from response: Eccezione durante una richiesta WebClient.
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this git issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4747) there's a workaround by using

```
 cabal --http-transport=plain-http update
```

instead. (forcing cabal not to use powershell's webclient)